# How to Get UPDATE to only affect one row (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my query:

```
$student_id = 34;
$user_id = 1;
$lesson_id = 25;

$query = ("UPDATE lessons SET 
assigned='1',
student_id='$student_id'
WHERE user_id='$user_id'
AND lesson_id='$lesson_id'")
```

I'm trying to run the UPDATE to affect only one row. I have a table like this:

```
_____________________________________
user_id|lesson_id|assigned|student_id
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |16       |1       |12
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |25       |0       |0
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |25       |0       |0
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |7        |1       |34
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |13       |1       |12
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |13       |0       |0
_______|_________|________|__________
```

When I execute this UPDATE, I find that ALL of the matching rows are updated. So if I try to update based on lesson_id 25, BOTH rows change. I only need one to change per query.

I tried adding LIMIT 1 to the query, but it only allowed me to do it once. I went back to the form and submitted all of the info to the query again, but it did not execute a second time. I thought that was odd.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: I should mention that the reason I have duplicates is that a while loop iterates through each instance to provide a selectable list that decreases with each assignment made.

Comment: There is nothing unique or distinct about those two records which makes it impossible to act upon one or the other. Why not add another field called `attempt` that will increment for each time a student is assigned the same lesson?

Comment: I think you really should look into your software and make some changes...

Comment: You need to filter by the you key, its a composite key?? Maybe its better you get all the fields that "lesson_id = 25" and get row by row and updating where unique key = unique key

Comment: First rule of database management: **All rows shall be unique.** Otherwise you are abusing the paradigm.

Comment: The problem is when you say to update where x = x and limit 1, aways it will bring the same row.

Comment: You have to use any Primary Key. There is no reason to save multiple rows with the same data...!!!!

Comment: Thanks. I did not design this DB - I'm just doing som code updates to it. All of your points are very well-taken - trust me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$query = ("UPDATE lessons SET 
    assigned='1',
    student_id='$student_id'
    WHERE user_id='$user_id'
    AND lesson_id='$lesson_id'
    AND assigned ='0' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This question does not make much sense. You have a table which has two exactly the same rows and your condition is to update these rows. So how do you want to limit the update?

You should add some unique column to identify records. Now all what you can do is LIMIT statement.

Your Where statement affects these rows:

```
user_id|lesson_id|assigned|student_id
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |25       |0       |0
_______|_________|________|__________
1      |25       |0       |0
_______|_________|________|__________
```

You should really think about redesigning your database. However, if it's not possible then use assigned field in **WHERE** condition. `WHERE assigned <> 1`